# Django Content Types - Can the value in ContentType for a modal change if modals are added or removed from application?

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes

While running test cases for Django, initially the value for a modal in ContentType is different than what I come across in test case. Any thoughts?

Comment: By modal, do you mean "model" ?

Comment: yup. sorry for the mistake

Comment: Absolutely. If you remove the model and then create it again, then django will create a new record in the ContentType table. Deleted ids from any table are not reproduced unless you manually give it the id.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of how you are writing the test case?